# How to prevent GWT DialogBox from being dragged out of the screen?

Tags: java, gwt

I am looking for a simple solution for the issue that my GWT `DialogBox` can be dragged out of the screen. The host has the CSS rule `overflow:hidden` because I do not want any scrollbars to appear.

Obviously I need to attach somehow a listener to the dragging and prevent moves that would bring it outside. I can only see `onMouseMove`, `beginDragging`, `endDragging` methods in `DialogBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"We" have worked around this issue in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void endDragging(MouseUpEvent event)
{
 int genericMargin = 60;

 int leftMargin = -(this.getOffsetWidth() - genericMargin);
 int lowerMargin = Window.getClientHeight() - genericMargin;
 int rightMargin = Window.getClientWidth() - genericMargin;
 int upperMargin = 0;

 if (this.getAbsoluteLeft() > rightMargin) 
 {this.setPopupPosition(rightMargin, this.getPopupTop()); }

 if (this.getAbsoluteLeft() < leftMargin) 
  { this.setPopupPosition(leftMargin, this.getPopupTop()); }

 if (this.getAbsoluteTop() > lowerMargin) 
 { this.setPopupPosition(this.getPopupLeft(), lowerMargin);}

 if (this.getAbsoluteTop() < upperMargin) 
 { this.setPopupPosition(this.getPopupLeft(), upperMargin);}

 super.endDragging(event);
}
```

BTW it correctly works as it is! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying gwtquery-dnd. I have been using the drag and drop plugin and it works great. It has an option to setContianment(Element elem) which is what you are looking for. Some other features is that it has snap so you can snap to other widgets if you wish to dock your dialog box somewhere. It also has the ability to specify a handle similar to the DialogBox header for dragging.

http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox source code and override all methods for your need. There are a couple of methods responsible for dragging there.

Not sure you can solve this problem in other ways. Otherwise you need to develop custom draggable popup panel which I am sure not a good solution.