# GWT: prevent dialog from moving off screen

Tags: java, gwt

All dialog windows can be moved off screen (horizontally or vertically, doesn't matter). When this window is behind screen, one can continue dragging it further and the content of the screen will move.

It sounds difficult to understand, but at the end it looks like this:
[image]

The following changes in `css` don't help a lot:

```
body {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    ...
}


html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Vertical and horizontal scroll bars don't appear when dialog window is moved there. But if there's a dialog window that has greater size than main screen, scroll bars also won't appear - and this is another problem.

How to prevent dialog window from moving off screen (fast example, dialog windows in google drive - they only move in visible part of screen)?

Comment: This is what you need ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211331/how-to-prevent-gwt-dialogbox-from-being-dragged-out-of-the-screen

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, it didn't work for me. I made my own implementation of `endDragging` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to solution I was looking for by overriding `endDragging` method of DialogBox. Here it is:

```
@Override
protected void endDragging(MouseUpEvent event)
{
    //Move dialog window behind top border
    if(this.getAbsoluteTop() < 0) {
        this.setPopupPosition(this.getPopupLeft(), 0);
    }
    //Move dialog window behind bottom border
    if(this.getAbsoluteTop() > (Window.getClientHeight() - this.getOffsetHeight())) {
        this.setPopupPosition(this.getPopupLeft(), Window.getClientHeight() - this.getOffsetHeight());
    }

    //Move dialog window behind left border
    if(this.getAbsoluteLeft() < 0) {
        this.setPopupPosition(0, this.getPopupTop());
    }
    //Move dialog window behind right border
    if(this.getAbsoluteLeft() > (Window.getClientWidth() - this.getOffsetWidth())) {
        this.setPopupPosition(Window.getClientWidth() - this.getOffsetWidth(), this.getPopupTop());
    }
    super.endDragging(event);
}
```

When dialog box is moved off the screen, it appears in visible part of the screen after mouse release. One can improve it and override `continueDragging` in order to prevent window from moving off screen at all.